# Replace leading spaces in string with zero in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I want to print a series of time periods in this format `yyyymm`, eg. `1970010600` to `1980010600` so I get the input as a string and convert the substring to integer, increment it and convert it again to string.

I concatenated these string variable as `fln=yyyy//mm`, but my output has leading blank spaces. I've used blank descriptors also its not working:

My output is `1971 1`, but I need `197101`. If it is a two digit month there is no problem.

How can I have a leading zero rather than a leading blank for the month?

A part of the code is:

```
integer:: m,j,n,k
character(len=12)::fln,st,et
character(len=4)::yy,tt
character(len=2)::mm,dd

 do j=0,k
 ma(j)=m+j
 write(mm,'(BZ,I2)')ma(j)
 fln=yy//mm
 write(19,121)fln
 121 format(A12)
```

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
write(mm,'(BZ,I2)')ma(j)
```

with

```
write(mm,'(I2.2)')ma(j)
```

then consult your Fortran reference material on the use of `I` edit descriptors of the form `Iw.m`.  The `BZ` edit control descriptor is useful for input only.